# Automatically change text color based on background color-Android studio/Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, text, background-color

I've only been working in Android Studio for a few weeks, so this is a bit new to me. I'm making a color picker app using Kotlin. I'm almost done, but I'm facing one dilemma. When a color is chosen, it replaces the background color. I'm trying to figure out how to change the color of the text from black to white when the user chooses a darker color and vise versa. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

As you can see in here: https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_rgb.asp
the higher the RGB value, the ligther the color will be.
Knowing this, you can create an if() else() structure testing the background color, so that if it is higher then X number of your choice, the text color changes.

For example (I'm not using real methods, it is just for explanation) :

```
if(background.color() >= (150,0,0) || backgroung.color() >= (0,150,0) || backgroung.color() >= (0,0,150)){

   textView.setTextColor(color.black)

}
else{

   textView.setTextColor(color.white)

}
```